# Image won't display on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Just started out using Java and am a beginner. I tried to create a photo viewer which can search a directory for an image and open the image but my program won't display the image.

When i run the program, it opens up and shows a menubar which i use to search my directories, but even if i select an image it won't display. TIA.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ICS
{
private JPanel gui;
private JFileChooser fileChooser;
FilenameFilter fileNameFilter;
private JMenuBar menuBar;
DefaultListModel model; 
public ICS() {
    gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    final JLabel imageView = new JLabel();
    gui.add(imageView);

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    String[] imageTypes = ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes();

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("GET PHOTO HERE");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenuItem browse = new JMenuItem("browse");
    menu.add(browse);

    browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(gui);
                if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File eg = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                }
            }
        }); 
}

public void loadImages(File directory) throws IOException {
    File[] imageFiles = directory.listFiles(fileNameFilter);
    BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[imageFiles.length];
}

public Container getGui() {
    return gui;
}

public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
    return menuBar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                ICS imageList = new ICS();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Browser");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(imageList.getGui());
                f.setJMenuBar(imageList.getMenuBar());
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(800,600);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything with your selected file. Given that you have an empty `JLabel` in your `JPanel`, you could simply set the `Icon` for that component:

```
imageView.setIcon(new ImageIcon(eg.getPath()));
```

Comment: Is there a specific place I would have to add it to?

Comment: While at first glance this appears to be correct, I would refrain from just saying "this is how it's done" and at least give an explanation of what he did wrong so that he learns to think for himself and does not make the same mistake again.

Comment: In the action listener right after you retrieve your selected file, like I said my answer.

Comment: @SevenBits "You're not doing anything with your selected file." I think that's all the explanation he needs. Code is more useful anyway so he actually knows what to do with it. In any case, OP, I also recommend turning on warnings for unused local variables in your IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA, etc.) so that you can spot problems like this more quickly. If it had been enabled, you would've seen the warning, usually a yellow underline, and been able to mouse over it to see the problem.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help everyone, I'll keep all the advice in mind. 
The program works fine now. :)

Comment: Awesome, glad we could help.

Comment: @Brian: But code is like the give a man rather than teach him to fish kind of thing. Code examples are fine, but you need to understand **why** it works the way it does rather than just copy and pasting code, otherwise when you move on the coding applications with dozens of source files you'll get floundered just looking for bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing anything with the image because you've never told it to. In your action listener, you've created a file chooser and gotten the selected file, but you never do anything with it. You just define it as a local variable inside the action listener, which is then immediately destroyed when your listener exits.

What you should be doing is, inside of your action listener, make a function call that actually displays your image after you retrieve the file the user selected.

Also, ICS is a terrible name for a class. You should be descriptive of your class names for your own reference and sanity when your program gets larger and you're trying to remember what everything did.